# Trying to replicate a function from excel to Tableau

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ifs

My excel file contains a column which is called shape, so I am trying to replicate this formula in an excel file to the calculate de volume for each of my shapes. My idea was by using an ifs statement. Let me know what you think. Thanks!

This is the formula in Tableau:

````
    WHEN 'Box' THEN [Width] * [Length] * [Depth]
    WHEN 'Flat' THEN [Width] * [Length] * [Depth]
    WHEN 'Ball' THEN ( (4/3) * PI() * ([Width]/2) * ([Length]/2) * ([Depth]/2) )
    WHEN 'Cylinder' THEN ( PI() * ([Width]/2) * ([Depth]/2) * [Length] )
    WHEN 'Bag' THEN ( SQUARE(([Width]*2)) / (PI()*4) * [Length] * 0.35 )
ELSE NULL END```
````

Comment: Your question make no sense. You can use IFS() function. There may other ways to solve your problem. Show some sample data and expected output for better understanding.

Comment: The algorithm is very clear.. mind sharing where exactly (in the ifs() or choose() function) that you are stuck at?.. a sample tried and filed/or partially work function would help (for others to assist)..